# Why does the print to stdout not happen when using fprintf?

Tags: c, stdout, stderr, printf

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
        while(1)
        {
                fprintf(stdout,"hello-out");
                fprintf(stderr,"hello-err");
                sleep(1);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The output is `hello-err` `hello-err` `hello-err` `hello-err` `hello-err` `hello-err`
at 1 sec intervals.
I want to know why hello-out never gets printed.

Comment: Great, clear question. +111111!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to `fflush` `stdout` because usually `stdout` is line buffered and you don't issue a new line character in your program.

```
            fprintf(stdout,"hello-out");
            fflush(stdout);
```

`stderr` is not fully buffered by default so you don't need to `fflush` it.

Answer (score 2):

stdout is line-buffered by default, meaning that the buffer will be flushed at every end-of-line (`'\n`').
stderr is unbuffured, so every character is sent automatically without the need to flush.

You can confirm this by placing a `\n` at the end of the stdout output. That way both lines will be printed at 1 second intervals.